# Angularjs iterating in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My aim is to display the list of items along with their respective count and description.I'm getting item name and count into the table. Can anyone tell me how to get description into the table by mapping `itemName`?

```js
var c = angular.module('myApp', []);
c.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    count: {
      "Item 1": 10,
      "Item 2": 20
    },
    items: [{
      "itemDescription": "Item Description",
      "itemName": "Item 1",
    }, {
      "itemDescription": "Item Description",
      "itemName": "Item 2",
    }]
  }

  $scope.name = "Demo"

})
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <table border="2">
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Description</td>
      <td>Count</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in data.count">
      <td>{{key}}</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `count` is an object, so $index isn't numeric.

Comment: @JeremyDentel Ah, right. My mistake

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason your data is structured as separate counts and items? If you retrieve them this way, it may be better to pre-process the data once retrieved to add the counts into their matching`data.items` array. If you don't want to pre-process the data, I would suggestion you `ng-repeat` on your `items` array as your counts object is easily queried.

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app= "myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <table border="2">
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Count</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in data.items">
        <td>{{item.itemName}}</td>
        <td>{{item.itemDescription}}</td>
        <td>{{data.count[item.itemName]}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer, imo

Answer (score 1):

Use a method

.html

```
<td>
  {{getDescription(key)}}
</td>
```

.js

```
getDescription(key) {
  const foundItem = $scope.data.items.find(item => item.itemName === key);
  return foundItem ? foundItem.itemDescription : '';
}
```

Comment: Should be `return ...find(...).itemDescription;` But that will error if find comes back null, so you'll have to do something like `return ...(find(..) || {}).itemDescription;`

Answer (score 1):

Create a new array and put the values from `count` into it. Then `ngRepeat` that new array

```js
var c = angular.module('myApp', []);
c.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    count: {
      "Item 1": 10,
      "Item 2": 20
    },
    items: [{
      "itemDescription": "Item Description",
      "itemName": "Item 1",
    }, {
      "itemDescription": "Item Description",
      "itemName": "Item 2",
    }]
  }

  var getCountsKeys = Object.values($scope.data.count);
  $scope.newArray = $scope.data.items.map(function(elem, index) {
    elem.itemVal = getCountsKeys[index]
    return elem;

  })

  $scope.name = "Demo"

})
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <table border="2">
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Description</td>
      <td>Count</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="nw in newArray">
      <td>{{nw.itemName}}</td>
      <td>{{nw.itemDescription}}</td>
      <td>{{nw.itemVal}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Although I would suggest preprocessing the data in a way similar to this, this is prone to potential errors if your count data does not match order directly. If by chance there is an `A Item` that comes before `Item 1` in the counts object, but the object in `items` that corresponds to `A Item` is not first, you now have the wrong counts attached to the values. Since you have the keys under `itemName`, you can query the `count` object directly `$scope.data.count[elem.itemName]` to guarantee the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a function which will return the description by iterating through the data-items.

```js
var c = angular.module('myApp',[]);
c.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
$scope.data={
    count: {
                "Item 1": 10,
                "Item 2" : 20,
                "Item 4": 30
            },
    items : [{
           "itemDescription": "Description 1",
            "itemName": "Item 1",
    },{
           "itemDescription": "Description 2",
            "itemName": "Item 2",
    },{
           "itemDescription": "Description 3",
            "itemName": "Item 3",
    }]
}
  
  $scope.name = "Demo";

$scope.getDescription = (item) => {
    const desc = $scope.data.items.find(i => i.itemName === item);
    return desc && desc.itemDescription // for exception handling
}
  
})
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app= "myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <table border="2">
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Count</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in data.count">
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td>{{getDescription(key)}}</td>
        <td>{{value}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: That will error if `find` comes back null, so you'll have to do something like `return ...(find(..) || {}).itemDescription;`